# Localization of the pullback diagram

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, limits-and-colimits, localization

In the paper, [Topologically Defined Classes of Commutative Rings](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj47P6Zp9_RAhXFFiwKHabcAB8QFgghMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mat.uniroma3.it%2Fusers%2Ffontana%2Fdocuments%2FFontana-AnnMatPA-80.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGIKDglVjFV737cTRGhxjXD1UDq8A&sig2=dbJsR7tr9dJ25EBAb5HwUw), localization of the pullback diagram (with $v,$ surjective)
$$
\begin{array}
 DD & \stackrel{v\ '}{\longrightarrow} & A \\
\downarrow{u' } & & \downarrow{u} \\
 B & \stackrel{v}{\longrightarrow} & C 
\end{array}
$$
is given as Proposition 1.9:
... Conversely, if $S_A$ is a multiplicatively closed set of $A$ and if $S_B$ is a multiplicatively closed  of $B$ and if $u(S_A)=v(S_B)=S_C$ then  $S_A^{-1}A \times_{S_C^{-1}C}S_B^{-1}B \cong (S_A \times_{S_C}S_B)^{-1} D.$

I can not see how a typical element of one side mapped to the other side by this isomorphism.
Can you help please?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you expect that the pullback (as a special kind of limit) should be the target of your map. Thus you expect a map:
$$(S_A \times_{S_C}S_B)^{-1} D\longrightarrow S_A^{-1}A \times_{S_C^{-1}C}S_B^{-1}B$$
Denote $S=S_A \times_{S_C}S_B$. In this setting you have $S=v'^{-1}(S_A)\cap u'^{-1}(S_B)$. So that it is naturally a multiplicative subset of $D$. In your context the localization $S^{-1}D$ is the set of pairs or formal quotients $d/s$ modulo identifications. Then $S_A^{-1}A \times_{S_C^{-1}C}S_B^{-1}B\subseteq S_A^{-1}A \times S_B^{-1}B$ is a subset so that you define:
$$ d/s\mapsto (v'(d)/v'(s),u'(d)/u'(s))$$
and you verify, that this agrees with the appropriate identifications and that both elements of the pair on the right are mapped to the same element of $S_C^{-1}C$.